# Java Input stream appending without deleting

Tags: java, file, append

How can I append data in file without making it clean after `FileInputStream(...)`?

That's how I append from my `HashMap <String, String> storage`:

```
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.dat"));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : storage.entrySet()) {
        byte[] bytesKey = entry.getKey().getBytes("UTF-8"); //I need to write using UTF8
        stream.writeInt(bytesKey.length);
        stream.write(bytesKey);
        byte[] bytesVal = entry.getValue().getBytes("UTF-8");
        stream.write(bytesVal);
    }
    stream.close();
```

So, the problem is when I turn it on again it clears all the previous data in my file. How to avoid that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add true parameter to the FileOutputStream so that it will append

```
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.dat", true));
```

Comment: No, the problem is when I turn my program on again it clears all the previous data in my file. How to avoid that? Flag `true` doesn't solve this problem

Comment: You solve this by constructing the FileOutputStream the way I have explained so that it starts in append mode

Comment: Look: 

1) I start program 

2) Write data in my file

3) Terminate program

4) Open file and I see all the data I wrote

5) Start  program again

6) Write smth again

7) Terminate

8) Look at file, BUT there's no data that I wrote the first time. There's only the last data I appended last time. That's the problem

Comment: I'm sorry. It's so bad that it's forbidden to say bad words here, I'm so scattered. The problem was that one of my 8 functions called PrintWriter so it cleared all data... Thank You! =)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone who see this answer, please, be as attentive as possible. I spent whole day to solve this problem just beacuse one of my classes called `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myfilename", "UTF8"));` so this cleared my file.

Good luck!